# Capture Oracle raise_applicaiton_error in Sequel

Tags: ruby, oracle, stored-functions

I have a Ruby script that calls a stored procedure in an Oracle DB that has a function that checks if a table is locked.  If the table is locked, the procedure generates a raise_application_error (-20001,...)

How do I capture that raise_application_error in my Ruby script?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get this to work:

```html
# Lock unit test before all test classes run
...connect to DB
begin
  err = nil
  ...call stored procedure to lock db
rescue
  puts $!.message
  err = $!.message
  puts "DB is locked. Retrying in 5 seconds"
  sleep(5)
  retry if err.include? "ORA-20001"
end

# Unlock unit test
...call stored procedure to unlock db
```